# Android Unity vuforia game resolution too short

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Can anyone please advise why the UI elements in the android application are too little comparing to the ones in the unity editor?

Have to mention that when I start the game in the editor on pc looks ok.

Please see the differences in the screens.
Maybe there are some settings IDK.
I am a beginner to Unity/Android games.

1. The [android phone](https://ibb.co/2nbPF7v) image.
   [image]
2. The [unity editor](https://ibb.co/Qj9sFrV) image.
   [image]

Comment: use the canvas scaler component in the canvas, set it to scale with screen size with 0.5 value. That will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please advise why the UI elements in the android
>   application are too little comparing to the ones in the unity editor?

That's because they have different Resolutions and aspect ratios.

[image]

Select different values to test how your game will look on display with different aspect ratios. This is set to Free Aspect by default.

To understand how ui scales in unity, read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html) manual.